# How to draw underline text with UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, underline

Hi I am new to IPhone paltfom.
And I wonder how can I underline a text with UIWebView?
I know this is quite simple, but I couldn't get any clue from the menual

can anybody show me some code snippet?

The text should be a passed-in parameter.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML content loaded by UIWebView, use

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">text-to-underline</span>
```

or

```
<u>text-to-underline</u>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to work properly for me.   and  and  tags work, but not , or CSS  "text-decoration: underline;"  It may be that the underline is not being scaled up as high as the rest of the page - e.g., a bug.  I'm not sure